# Entity Framework: Foreign key with a different type

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework

I've to do an import from an old database (In oracle) a lot of data to an SQL Server database.  This import will be done every night, and can be launched from .net application(asp or heavy client)

I'm using the devart connector to the database.

I finished to configure the database connection and started to create an edmx with only data that I'm interessted to.

I encountered a weird thing:
It seems that the foreign key is an Number(10)(translated in int64), and the referenced primary key is a Number(8)(translated in an int32).

I've just no freaking idea why it has be done like this and there is no way that I can ever dream once to change this( :( ).

The problem is that I got errors in my model:

```
Error 112: The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential 
constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal 
Role. The type of property 'GSM_ID' on entity 'My.NameSpace.Store.GG_IRTSPEZ' does
not match the type of property 'ID' on entity 'My.NameSpace.Store.GG_STAMM' in the 
referential constraint 'ORACLE_GIRT_GSM_FK'.
```

Do you have any idea about how to workaround this problem?

Comment: Can you create a View to convert them to the same type?

Comment: Have you tried creating a DefiningQuery to mimic a view? ie: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc982038.aspx

Comment: You could try to cheat and change the `Int64` to an `Int32` in your EDMX (should be possible in designer surface). I believe it will be overwritten though if you update the model from DB, so you would have to change the type again.

Comment: I can change it, but after this, it sees that I set an Int32 and my database has an Int64. Then I got an exception when I'm trying to use it.

Comment: Can I ask how you've fixed this?